# Xubutnu 18.04.4 login loop issues

Tags: xubuntu

My laptop was running fine until I tried to install flutter without using android studio.Eventually,flutter got installed.but login loop persists

> The command could not be located because '/usr/bin:/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable
>
> Lesspipe: command not found
>   Command dircolors is available in '/usr/bin/dircolors'
>
> The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable
>   dircolors:command not found

Ps: when I did echo $PATH
i got  /usr/lib/flutter/bin

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing happening to me, and I performed a new installation. That caused me problem with my manager, and now I have the same problem again after installing flutter and Android studio.

At this moment, I don't know what to do because I need the data in my laptop.

I think that Android Studio comes with the latest Java and that causes  problems.